# Replace accented characters into not accented characters + an "apostrophe" in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, diacritics

i would like to replace the accented character with the same character without the accent and add an apostrophe.
For example:

`città universitaria` > `citta' universitaria`
`Via Libertà` > `Via Liberta'`

I used:

```
SELECT CONVERT ('città universitaria', 'US7ASCII', 'UTF8')
FROM dual;
```

It returns "citta universitaria", and it's fine but I need to add the apostrophe after the "a".

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple REGEXP_REPLACE to add the apostroph - add other characters that you need to transform in the first pattern `([àèòìù])`

```
select
REGEXP_REPLACE('città universitaria', '([àèòìù])', q'{\1'}') txt
FROM dual;

TXT                 
--------------------
città' universitaria
```

The complete query

```
SELECT CONVERT (REGEXP_REPLACE('città universitaria', '([àèòìù])', q'{\1'}'), 'US7ASCII', 'UTF8') txt
FROM dual;

TXT                 
--------------------
citta' universitaria
```

Comment: Ok that's work. But there is any method to do this with all the accents? For example è, ò, ì, ù?

Comment: Yep, simple add them all in the pattern e.g. `([àèòìù])`

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much! May I ask you if there is any chance even to replace Arabic numerals in Roman numerals? For examples 1 > I,  5> V. I don't think there is a different coding to convert that

Comment: @GianlucaCHIAVETTA use e.g. `to_char(5, 'RN')`